# How to use sample_weight parameter for algorithms in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've a very imbalanced dataset and I'm performing a classification task. So i've tried all the algorithms i.e (Decision Trees, Naive Bayes, Logistic Regression) and for each of them I've come across a parameter called `sample_weights` in scikit learn.

Assume in my dataset I've around 100k positive data points and 20k negative data points.
i.e `0.83 %` of positive labels and `0.16 %` of negative labels

From the docs I assume this parameter is used to tackle such issue by giving more weightage to class with less data points i.e imbalaned dataset.

> class_weight : dict or ‘balanced’, default: None
>
> Weights associated with classes in the form {class_label: weight}. If
> not given, all classes are supposed to have weight one. For
> multi-output problems, a list of dicts can be provided in the same
> order as the columns of y.

*My question is what should be my ideal class_weights for the above imbalanced dataset example such that I could avoid techniques like oversampling or undersampling?*

Answer (score 2):

The weights should be set to `balanced` so that the classes are trained as if they were balanced.

Class weights are equivalent to **random oversampling**. In my opinion, intelligent oversampling techniques such as [SMOTE](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html#imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE) is a more efficient method over the the method of adding weights to samples during training.

However, oversampling techniques have an added **computation cost**, because the model needs to be trained on a *larger* dataset (due to oversampling). Class weighting, on the other hand has **no** additional computation cost to the model. Unless training a very *computationally expensive* model, I usually prefer SMOTE.

Comment: Do I've to use SMOTE on the total dataset(not splitted) or just on X_train?

Comment: You should **only** use SMOTE on the training set. Any evaluation performed should be on a set that **hasn't** been resampled, or else your results won't be reliable!

Comment: You mentioned techniques like `sample_weight` are computationally expensive. Isn't `SMOTE` also doing the same thing i.e oversampling?

Comment: Sorry I wrote that wrong, I meant that oversampling is more computationally expensive because it trains the model on larger dataset. Sample weights **don't** have an added computational cost, but usually they don't perform as well as oversampling techniques like SMOTE. If your model isn't very computationally expensive as is, I'd recommend oversampling.